# Is there a tool I can use to see all the chains of a particular Hadith matn/text, and its variant wordings?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

i want to find out all the hadith books and chains a particular hadith is transmitted to us by, is there an online site I can use to look something like that up?
Preferably with page references.

I probably should have asked this question before I started (and promptly gave up on) this monstrous task by myself lol.

Comment: May expectation is that you'll find for all printed hadith collections a cross-reference for all hadith/hadith parts not only for the full matn/text. I'd even assume that full narrator chains mentioned by scholars elsewhere wouldn't be referenced for example narrations of imam a-Dhahhabi in his siyar a'alaam an-Nubala' where he shows examples of hadiths from his memory/study which he memorized and which include the person as the narrator. I don't know of any tool, but some sites that do such "ikhraaj" based on the books they have in their own data base. However there are some hadith sw-tools.